# Confuse about Bitmap convert to ByteArray in different way

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, bitmap

I have searched 3 ways to convert a Bitmap object to ByteArray but the result return 3 sizes of ByteArray. How's the differences between them?

The image I tested from [here](https://www.unitag.io/images/generator/templates/classic.png) with dimension is 300x300.

Here's my testing code and result.

```
val bitmapTarget = Glide
            .with(_context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load("https://www.unitag.io/images/generator/templates/classic.png")
            .submit()

        val bitmap = bitmapTarget.get()

        val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.byteCount)
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer)
        val byteFromBuffer = byteBuffer.array() // 360000 bytes

        val byteOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteOutputStream)
        val byteJpeg = byteOutputStream.toByteArray() // 25408 bytes

        val byteOutputStream2 = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteOutputStream2)
        val bytePng = byteOutputStream2.toByteArray() // 4238 bytes
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: `compress(...JPEG...)`, `compress(...PNG...)` are a different format (compressed?!) than `copyPixels...` - a ZIP, a GZIP (just as example, not used on above code) and an uncompressed file will also have different sizes... having smaller size is the reason to use compression

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
bmp.recycle();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.